# Adding column with dates, hours and minutes + giving existing columns a name

Tags: python, date, date-range

I want to read from an excel with 200 electricity consumption profiles of every quarter of a whole year. So from 01/01/20 00:00:00 till 31/12/20 23:45:00. the first column enumerates from 0-33599 but represents the date. This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
data = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/User/Desktop/Map1.csv', header=None)
print(data) 
data('date')=pd.date_range(start='01/01/20 00:00:00', periods=len(data),freq='15T')
```

[The image shows my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUhx0.png)

[33600 rows x 200 columns]

and an error message: SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call

**what can I do to add this date column instead of the numbers 0:33599 and how can I name my columns? like naming column 0 : load profile 1**